# how to calculate cyclomatic complextity, memory usage, Page fault, etc in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I had went though one puzzle contest, where our solution is graded based on these factor
cyclomatic complexity, memory usage, Page fault, execution time etc.

Is there is way to calculate the cyclomatic complexity, memory usage, Page fault, execution time,etc in eclipse? any plugins for these.

I came to know that [metrics](http://metrics.sourceforge.net/) plugin supports the complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Cyclomatic complexity: PMD plugin
- Memory usage and Execution time: Any profiler
- Page fault: not sure